# Universal gotoXY implementation in C++

Tags: c++, cursor, konsole

I have something like this:

```
 ______________________
/\                     \
\_| 1. Menu entry one  |
  | 2. Menu entry two  |
  | The user's choice:X|
  |   _________________|_
   \_/___________________/
```

I'm working on Linux so I can't use the conio.h to move the cursor to the X position.
Besides that writing my own gotoXY function would be pointless because
resizing the terminal emulator would screw everything up.
How can achieve my goal?

Comment: What is your goal? Sounds like you want to use ncurses.

Comment: For text-mode drawing, windowing, etc., under Linux (and also portable to Windows) consider using curses.

Comment: @1 My goal is to start writing (std::cin >> x) after the ":" (colon). Thank you. I will try to use the ncurses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

Try messing around with the CSI n B and CSI n D options.